# AnimatedVisibility in Row in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
internal fun AnimatedGrid(
    blocks: List<Blocks>
) {
    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        maxItemsInEachRow = 3,
        content = {
            blocks.forEachIndexed { index, block ->
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = true,
                    enter = fadeIn(
                        initialAlpha = 0.0f,
                    ),
                    exit = fadeOut(
                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 3000),
                        targetAlpha = 1.0f
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                ) {
                    Block(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
                        label = block.type,
                        description = block.variant
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I want to get results where when open screen I want to see first element show from invisible to visible, after that second element show from zero to visible etc. One by one. How can I get effect like that?